# How to prompt user in a Gherkin test?

Tags: gherkin, python-behave

We are using Gherkin/Behave (in Python) to test an embedded application. The Gherkin code is executed on a server while the actual activity is performed by an application on the device, communicating over the network. The application on the device needs to be started manually.

I need a test to reboot the device. I can get the test application to perform a reboot, but then I need the code on the server to prompt the user to restart the test app so that the test can continue with subsequent steps. However I cannot get the Python code in the "steps" file to output any text.

I appreciate that Gherkin/Behave is meant to provide fully automated testing, but real world restrictions apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for formatter in context._runner.formatters:
    formatter.stream.write("Your message here\n")
    formatter.stream.write("\n")
```

The extra newline is needed because Behave prints a description of the step first, then overwrites it in green if it passed. The extra newline ensures that this overwrite overwrites a blank line rather than your text.

Note that when I tested this I was using the default "pretty" formatter. I don't know how well it will work with other formatters.

Comment: After some experimentation I found that it might be that the formatter writes the step over two (or potentially more) lines and thus extra new lines were required. My final solution, since the displayed prompt was only needed temporarily, was to delete the text by printing ANSI control codes just before the step ended. The formatter was then able to recolour the step description as usual, and no extra newlines were needed.